# Open several asp.net pages inside tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have an asp.net page which should load several pages inside itself in separate tabs (like yahoo mail new style). how should I achieve this?

Comment: I have used load function of jQuery and tab control. I can open each page inside tabs but after post-back from each page inside tab (for example for delete or update) it redirects to a new page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so instead of loading the pages with ajax, add them as iframes. This way when you post in one of them, it will only reload that tab, and the rest will be untouched

Comment: Yes. finally we did it using Tabcontrol of ajaxtoolkit and iframe :) There is a sample here http://forums.asp.net/t/1532225.aspx/1